# How to detect movement edge from fixed edge with Python Opencv? for specific length detection

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, object-detection

Currently I have a project that related to measure the fabric's length detection that i hope to use openCV python for programming.

Here is my idea in the below image,and please give me any suggestions on whether the measured length can be achieved using openCv?
I can elaborate on this if anything unclear of the whole process.

**Keyword** :
Fabric edge lay on the table (start to detect the edge) -> cut the fabric to produce the other edge
Calculation : Edge to Edge distance
Help : What kind of tool should i use ? openCV+ROI+Camera capturing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1siD.png)

Im expecting real-time object edge detection with python alorithm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).